# Htaccess redirect by language, except if user comes from an inbound link. How?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, hyperlink

So, I have the following code in my Htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (es) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/es/ [R,L]
```

As you see, I am redirecting Spanish browser language users to Spanish version of the site. This way, even if I have a link on a Spanish version page to a English language version of the site, users have no way of seeing it as the redirect turns them back to Spanish version no matter what.

What can I do to allow Spanish language users who are already redirected to Spanish page, by a click on an "English Version" link to access the actual English version page?

Comment: This is what you're doing: http://xkcd.com/869/ - I don't want your home page unless I asked for your home page, don't redirect me to it, redirect me to the article/page I wanted.

Comment: @scragar I'm not following you. What did you want me to say? Did you help me to answer my question? My site is a 1 page site. What's wrong if I am showing a Spanish speaking visitor a page especially written for him? I don't redirect any side pages to homepage, since everything I have is homepage and a Spanish homepage :)

Comment: So you don't have any inbound links then? Because if you dont have any other pages, then certainly you don't need links to get people to them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to set a cookie when you first automatically redirect the user. If that cookie exists, then do nothing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !language=(en|es)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (es) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/es%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,CO=language:es:www.example.com:9999]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !language=
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=language:en:www.example.com:9999,L]
```

Comment: If I wanted to add more languages that point to ES page, how will your code look?